# Posting message from web worker results in infinite message loop

Tags: javascript, webpack, web-worker

I am trying to learn how to use Web Workers with webpack. I have a simple script that creates the web worker and sends it a message.

index.js:

```
const worker = new Worker("./assets/worker.js");
worker.postMessage({a: 1});
worker.onmessage = (event: MessageEvent) => {
    console.log("Message received from worker");
    console.log(event.data);
};
```

worker.js:

```
onmessage = async (event: MessageEvent) => {
    console.log("Received message from main script");
    console.log(event.data);
    postMessage({n: "From worker"}, "*");
};
```

However as soon as I start the page, it gets into an infinite loop and I have to force-quit Firefox:

[image]

What I noticed is that the messages look like they are being sent to the web worker, but the message content is what's supposed to be received from the web worker.

I don't know much about web workers, and I don't know much about combining it with webpack. My webpack config looks like this:

```
entry: {
        index: "./src/index.tsx",
        worker: "./src/workers/KeepAlive.worker.ts"
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].js",
        publicPath: "assets/",
        path: srcPath(outputDirectory),
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
    },
...
```

So how can I fix this?

Comment: Is this really all you have? When is this script executed?

Comment: No, it's part of a larger react application. But there's no other code in my codebase dealing with postmessage or web workers at all. This is the only code related to the web workers installation and use. I can't post everything because it's a business project.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, kinda. In the worker code,

```
postMessage({n: "From worker"}, "*");
```

shouldn't have the second argument. I guess that passes the message back to the worker or something. I thought it was needed because VSCode was giving me this method signature from `lib.dom.ts`:

```
declare function postMessage(message: any, targetOrigin: string, transfer?: Transferable[]): void;
```

But I added a `tsconfig.json` file to my web workers folder:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "webworker",
        ]
    }
}
```

So now VSCode interprets the method signature as

```
declare function postMessage(message: any, options?: PostMessageOptions): void;
```

defined in `lib.webworker.d.ts`.